# search list of custom objects by its properties

Tags: java

I have list of ObjectLocation, declared as

```
List<ObjectLocation> myLocations;
```

And here's how ObjectLocation looks like:

```
public class ObjectLocation {
    int locationID, ratingCount = 0;
}
```

Ok now myLocations holds thousands of locationID. If I have a particular locationID, how do I search the contents of myLocations for the locationID, and get the searched locationID's index (within myLocations) and it's ratingCount?

Comment: Not sure why this is posted as a question in 2015 when there are a couple of search algorithms to choose from. Java itself provides a `binarySearch` method.

Comment: Yes search is a possibility but you would have to change the code for it and not everyone knows how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of lookup I'd switch to using a `Map<Integer, ObjectLocation>` and store entries in the map like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<ObjectLocation>> myLocationMap = new HashMap<>();
List<ObjectLocation> currentList = myLocationMap.get(oneLocation.locationID);
if(currentList == null) {
    // We haven't stored anything at this locationID yet,
    // so create a new List and add it to the Map under
    // this locationID value.
    currentList = new ArrayList<>();
    myLocationMap.put(oneLocation.locationID, currentList);
}
currentList.add(oneLocation);
```

Now you can quickly get all of the `ObjectLocation` entries with a specific value for `locationID` by grabbing them from the map like this:

```
List<ObjectLocation> listOfLocations = myLocationMap.get(someLocationId);
```

This assumes that multiple `ObjectLocation` instances can have the same `locationID` value. If not then you wouldn't need a `List<ObjectLocation>` in the map, just a single `ObjectLocation`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you loop through all of the elements in the list, and if the locationID match, you've found your element!

```
int idx=0;
for (ObjectLocation ol:myLocations){
  if (ol.locationID==searchedLocationID){
    // found at index idx!!  
  }
  idx++;
}
```

More efficiently, you could have a `Map<Integer,ObjectLocation>` where the key is the locationID of the ObjectLocation, to get much faster lookups.

Comment: Better put a `break` in the if so the loop stops there. Otherwise `idx` will just be `myLocations.size()`

Answer (score 0):

For you to easily search and find a your `ObjectLocation` objects, you should first define `.equals(Object o)` method,  in `ObjectLocation` class, that allows one `ObjectLocation` to be compared to another. After that, all you have to do is use `.indexOf(Object o)'` to get the index of the `ObjectLocation` you are looking for. Then extract that object and use its information as exemplified in the code below:

```
public class ObjectLocation {
    int locationID, ratingCount = 0;

    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
         if(!(o instanceof ObjectLocation))
         return false;

         ObjectLocation another = (ObjectLocation)o;
         if( locationID == another.locationID && ratingCount == another.ratingCount)
             return true;
         else
             return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<ObjectLocation> myLocations;
        ObjectLocation findThisLocation;
        ObjectLocation found;
        //Additional code here

        int index = myLocations.indexOf(findThisLocation);
        found = myLocations.get(index);
        int id = found.locationID;
        int rating = found.ratingCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ObjectLocation> myLocations = new ArrayList<>();

int index =0;
        int particularId = 1;//!your Id
        int locationid = 0;
        int ratingcount = 0;
        for(int i =0; i < myLocations.size(); i++) {
            if(myLocations.get(i).locationID == particularId) {
                index = i;
                locationid = myLocations.get(i).locationID;
                ratingcount = myLocations.get(i).ratingCount;
            }            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8, I would use (without changing anything on the data structure like using a `Map` instead or knowing about ordering in the list):

```
Optional<ObjectLocation> found = myLocations.stream()
  .filter(location -> location.locationID == particularLocationID)
  .findAny();
if (found.isPresent() {
  int ratingCount = found.get();
  …
}
```

When you need more performance for single searches, you may try `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()`.

Comment: Actually I'm doing this on android, and it seems there's no Optional class here

Comment: Optional is Java 8, as Java 7 is End of Life you should upgrade your project